# Opencart admin login

Tags: php, redirect, opencart

I am trying to my login admin panel in opencart. But its not redirect me on admin home page. after login its still on login page but url is changed. Please see url in address bar fine but not going on admin home page.

```
admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=b6273025d45373a085b46387bd6339d8
```

Comment: Did You install some administration theme? What is Your Firebug's console saying?

Comment: not giving any error..:( i am so confused what's the issue is going..

Comment: @LeeAustin: Is there any extension you installed before this error appers?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to try:

1. Disable `.htaccess file` and check.
2. Check the folder paths and other constants in `config` files.

Answer (score 1):

A common Issue on Shared Webhosting is that you will need to change the php.ini and set session.save_path to the right path.

A method to get the path is to use phps function getcwd in a phpinfo.php file and check the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but before I installed - EU Cookie Law extension and I edited .htacces file adding this lines:

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "eu-opt-in=1" opted_in
Header always unset Set-Cookie env=!opted_in
```

:D so when I deleted it everything becomes okay, my mistake was stupid because I didn’t accept cookies by my self and that’s why I can not login….

I home it will helpful for other people.